# ASP.NET Dropdown list into jquery variable

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have 2 code,

This is the First:

```
    $("#Button1")
    .click(function () {
        var index;            
        var select = $("#DropDownList1");
        var select = document.getElementById("DropDownList1");
        var myindex = ["zero", "one", "two", "three"];
        for (index = 0; index < myindex.length; index++) {
            select.appendChild(new Option(myindex[index]));
        }
    });
```

This is the Second:

```
    $("#Button1")
    .click(function () {
        var index;            
        var select = document.getElementById("DropDownList1");
        var myindex = ["zero", "one", "two", "three"];
        for (index = 0; index < myindex.length; index++) {
            select.appendChild(new Option(myindex[index]));
        }
    });
```

Why the first code doesn't work?

```
    var select = $("#DropDownList1");
```

I have to change it to

```
    var select = document.getElementById("DropDownList1");
```

I want to turn $("#DropDownList1") to a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`appendChild` is not a jquery function.

Assuming your first code has a paste-typo with the extra `document.getElementById`, you can use `select.get(0).appendChild()` to convert a jquery object to a DOM element.

```
    var index;            
    var select = $("#DropDownList1");
    var myindex = ["zero", "one", "two", "three"];
    for (index = 0; index < myindex.length; index++) {
        select.get(0).appendChild(new Option(myindex[index]));
    }
```

or you could continue with jquery, eg:

```
    for (index = 0; index < myindex.length; index++) {
        select.append("<option>" + myindex[index] + "</option>");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank u for @freedomn-m
Now i change my code to this:

```
        var index;            
        var select = $("#DropDownList1");            
        var myindex = ["zero", "one", "two", "three"];
        for (index = 0; index < myindex.length; index++) {
            select.append("<option>" + myindex[index] + "</option>");
        }
```